# Singleton instantiation creating multiple objects

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I am attempting to learn the Singleton design pattern and I came across the following example.  However, it seems that I am able to create multiple instances of the class.

I thought the point of a Singleton was to only allow a single instance of a class to be created at any given time.  Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?  How can I verify that only one object is being created at any given time?

```
public class ChocolateBoiler {
    private boolean empty;
    private boolean boiled;

    private static ChocolateBoiler uniqueInstance;

    private ChocolateBoiler(){
        empty = true;
        boiled = false;
    }

    public static synchronized ChocolateBoiler getInstance(){
        if(uniqueInstance == null){
            uniqueInstance = new ChocolateBoiler();
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

    public void fill(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("filling");
            empty = false;
            boiled = false;

        }
        System.out.println("already full");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        System.out.println("empty");
        return empty;

    }

    public boolean isBoiled(){
        System.out.println("boiled");
        return boiled;
    }

    public void drain() {
        if (!isEmpty() && isBoiled()) {
            System.out.println("draining");
            empty = true;
        }
        System.out.println("already empty");
    }

    public void boil(){
        if(!isEmpty() && isBoiled() ){
            System.out.println("boiled");
            boiled = true;
        }
        System.out.println("either empty or not boiled?");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChocolateBoiler boiler1 = new ChocolateBoiler();
        boiler1.fill();
        boiler1.boil();
        boiler1.boil();
        boiler1.drain();
        boiler1.drain();
        boiler1.isEmpty();


        System.out.println("\nboiler 2");
        ChocolateBoiler boiler2 = new ChocolateBoiler();
        boiler2.fill();

        System.out.println("\nboiler 1");
        boiler1.isBoiled();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is creating two instances?

Comment: Your singleton pattern is correct, you should invoke it from other classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the `ChocolateBoiler` class you have access to the private constructor, so you can create as many instances as you like (as you demonstrate in your `main` method).

The point of the Singleton pattern is that outside your class, only one instance of `ChocolateBoiler` can be obtained (via the `getInstance` method), since the private constructor can't be accessed from the outside.

Comment: Gotcha!  I knew it was going to be something simple.  Thank you.

Comment: So I tried to use `ChocolateBoiler tmp = ChocolateBoiler.getInstance();` and I'm getting a weird little error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: DesignPatterns.Singleton.ChocolateBoiler.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)` which is `throw new NoSuchMethodException(getName() + "." + name + argumentTypesToString(parameterTypes));` any idea?

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani It looks like an issue of cleanup of old compilations. Did you move your main method to a new class? How does your new code look like?

Comment: Yes that must be exactly what happened.  I moved main out of `ChocolateBoiler` into a separate class.